# How can I calculate percentage of a number in solidity?

Tags: solidity

How can I calculate percentage of a number in solidity? say I want to calculate 95% of the number `200`.

How should I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to calculate exact number by division in computer.

If just you want to get 95% of 200, 200/100 * 95 is the answer.
But if you ask how can i get exact number of result of division, it can't in some number.

Comment: isn't it `(200 * 95) / 100` ?

Comment: MATH :) hint it's the same

Comment: @pasevin not the same in solidity

Comment: @Richard Why do you say so?

```
function test1() public pure returns(uint) {
    return (200 * 95) / 100;
}
    
function test2() public pure returns(uint) {
    return 200 / 100 * 95;
}
```

Will return exactly the same result.

Comment: Im talking about cases where { return x / 100 * 95; }  and x is small enough to bring floating point errors.

Comment: Good point, thanks for clarifying.